# Получать все нотификации в windows 10

Tags: c#, c++, c, winapi

Нотификации (toast) о событиях в windows 10, как получать? Информации на эту тему не много, нашел класс `UserNotificationListener class`, но примера использования не нашел. Так-же есть упоминание о реестре и типах хранимых там идентификаторов нотификаций, что ситуацию не прояснило.

При этом интересуют все нотификации, для логирования и сохранения.

Comment: Смущают метки. На каком языке пишете? Приложение какого типа, под какую платформу?

Comment: Win32/64, язык разницы не имеет, `с/с++`, в крайнем случае `C#`, задача найти апи, как это получить, результат можно оформить например а виде длл или сервиса. Основной язык приложения `Managed C++`

Comment: Судя по описанию, использование UserNotificationListener весьма прямолинейное, главное читать раздел с пояснениями - прежде чем собирать оповещения в вашем UWP приложении необходимо запросить разрешения из GUI потока вызвав RequestAccessAsync.

Comment: Да, примерно так, прямолинейно.. в общем надо пробовать, на самом деле куски кода с этим классом нашлись на гитхабе, что не может не радовать.

Answer (score -1):

Судя по описанию, использование UserNotificationListener весьма прямолинейное, главное читать раздел с пояснениями - прежде чем собирать оповещения в вашем UWP приложении необходимо запросить разрешения из GUI потока вызвав RequestAccessAsync.

Comment: Вы решили показать навыки в области копи-паст текста?